# wxpython-Drawing on a transparent window

Tags: python, wxpython

I'm coding an application that needs to select an area of the screen. I need to change the cursor to a cross and then draw a rectangle on the user selection - this is successful (though an error keeps popping up that I'm using a 'deprecated' function - haven't figured how to fix this).

The main problem - when I change the window to becoming completely transparent (by setting self.SetTransparent(0)), the selection rectangle gets transparent too, so I can't get the window fully transparent and still see the selection.

Here's the code:

```
import wx

class SelectableFrame(wx.Frame):

    c1 = None
    c2 = None

    def __init__(self, parent=None, id=-1, title=""):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent, id, title, size=wx.DisplaySize())

        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, size=self.GetSize())
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_MOTION, self.OnMouseMove)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.OnMouseDown)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_UP, self.OnMouseUp)
        self.panel.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self.OnPaint)
        self.SetCursor(wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_CROSS))
        self.SetTransparent(10)

    def OnMouseMove(self, event):
        if event.Dragging() and event.LeftIsDown():
            self.c2 = event.GetPosition()
            self.Refresh()

    def OnMouseDown(self, event):
        self.c1 = event.GetPosition()

    def OnMouseUp(self, event):
        self.SetCursor(wx.StockCursor(wx.CURSOR_ARROW))

    def OnPaint(self, event):
        if self.c1 is None or self.c2 is None: return

        dc = wx.PaintDC(self.panel)
        dc.SetPen(wx.Pen('red', 2)) 
        dc.SetBrush(wx.TRANSPARENT_BRUSH) 
        dc.DrawRectangle(self.c1.x, self.c1.y, self.c2.x - self.c1.x, self.c2.y - self.c1.y)

    def PrintPosition(self, pos):
        return str(pos.x) + " " + str(pos.y)

class MyApp(wx.App):

    def OnInit(self):
        frame = SelectableFrame()
        frame.Show(True)
        self.SetTopWindow(frame)

        return True

app = MyApp(0)
app.MainLoop()
```

How do I make the window transparent but keep the selection visible?

Comment: To avoid the `deprecated` error change `wx.StockCursor` to `wx.Cursor`

Comment: Would you know the solution to the main problem though? Any help is welcome :)

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to do the way you're trying to do it (e. g. with transparent windows). At least on Windows OS. I may be wrong, my experience with this is rather limited, outdated and mostly related to C++/MFC, not wxPython. Why not leave the window opaque, though, but cut it so that only the rectangular line is visible?